# How to find which sql statements are executed in a transaction on Websphere AS 7.0?

Tags: sql, logging, transactions, jta, websphere-7

I have a `Websphere Application Server 7.0.0.9`, on which an application is running that uses `springframework 2.0.9` and `hibernate 3.3.0` (or 3.4.0, or both, I'm not sure). TransactionManager is `org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager`.

I have a method that is annotated as `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. This method calls another method that is also annotated as `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod() {
    doSomeUpdates();
    nestedMethod();
}
@Transactional
public void nestedMethod() {
    doSomeMoreUpdates();
}
```

The method "myMethod" is supposed to be atomary. Sometimes there is a bug when updates from "doSomeUpdates" are rolled back, but updates from "doSomeMoreUpdates" are commited.

Default propagation settings are `Propagation.REQUIRED`. I tried changing my code to:

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod() {
    doSomeUpdates();
    nestedMethod();
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public void nestedMethod() {
    doSomeMoreUpdates();
}
```

I tried looking in logs to find whether this change has solved my bug, but cannot make no heads no tails of the quagmire that is my log files. I'm logging sql statements via org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger class, and dump transactional trivia to websphere's trace.log file with the following settings:

```
com.ibm.wsspi.uow.*=finest: com.ibm.ws.uow.*=finest:
com.ibm.ws.jtaextensions.*=finest: org.hibernate.transaction.*=finest:
org.springframework.transaction.*=finest: com.ibm.ws.Transaction.*=finest:
com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.*=finest: com.ibm.ws.tx.*=finest:
oracle.jdbc.*=finest:
```

This produces *heaps* of useless data, but sql statements are dumped *only* by SQLStatementLogger that, it looks like, doesn't have anything to do with websphere transactions. How can I see which sql statements are really executed by websphere in each transaction?

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this problem last week. It seems like the specialized plug-in class WebSphereUowTransactionManager has been changed in Spring to adapt to Websphere 7.x

We were using Spring framework version 3.0.5 against a WebSphere 6.1 installation. However, when we migrated to WebSphere 7.1 we had similar problems to the ones you mentioned above. We went crazy for a while trying to figure out the problem until we upgraded our Spring framework to version 3.1.1. Now everything runs smoothly once again.

Best of luck.